# updating entity containing object fields

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to update entity which contains fields of type of another class.

so this is my entity:

```
@Entity
public class Owner {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    @NotNull(message="{NotNull}")
    @Size(min=2,max=15,message="{Size}")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull(message="{NotNull}")
    @Size(min=2,max=15,message="{Size}")
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Valid
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Phone phone;

    @Valid
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Pet pet;
```

from this view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>

<meta charset="ISO-8859-1"></meta>

<title>Owner details</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="owner">
        <form th:action="@{|/ownerList/${owner.id}.do|}"
            th:object="${owner}" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Id:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></td>
                    <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('id')}" th:errors="*{id}">fieldError</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>First name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}" /></td>
                    <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}"
                        th:errors="*{firstName}">fieldError</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}" /></td>
                    <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('lastName')}"
                        th:errors="*{lastName}">fieldError</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Phone</td>
                    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{phone.number}" /></td>
                    <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('phone.number')}"
                        th:errors="*{phones[0].number}">fieldError</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Pet</td>
                    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{pet.petName}" /></td>
                    <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('pet.petName')}"
                        th:errors="*{pet.petName}">fieldError</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="update" name="action" /></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="delete" name="action" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <a href="/ownerList">Back</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using this controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ownerList/{id}.do")
    public String ownerDetailsDo(@ModelAttribute(value = "owner") Owner owner, BindingResult result,
            @RequestParam(value = "action") String action, Model model) {


        switch (action) {
        case "update":
            ObjectBinder.bind(owner);
            ownerService.update(owner);
            return "ownerDetail";
        case "delete":
            ownerService.remove(owner.getId());
            model.addAttribute("ownerList", ownerService.getAll());
            return "ownerList";
        }
        model.addAttribute("owner", owner);
        return "ownerDetail";
    }
```

So I'm trying to update object of Owner, but inside of database after .merge I can find new entity of , for example Phone, with new Id.

so to make clear for example I have:
Owner:
first name:XYZ
last name: BBB
pet: BOB
phone: 1234

when I try to update phone, lets say to "2222", then in DB I can find two records 
one is "1234" second is "2222", and I want to have "2222" replaced the old one "1234".

Comment: In your controller update method doesn't know which phone number has to update for particular Owner Id. pass the owner id value from Jsp as a hidden value and Phone number with particular owner id as hidden value from jsp to get values in controller ,after that update your phone number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete the phone when is not referenced by any Owner then you need to add @OrphanRemoval.

> Orphan Removal in Relationships When a target entity in one-to-one or
>   one-to-many relationship is removed from the relationship, it is often
>   desirable to cascade the remove operation to the target entity. Such
>   target entities are considered “orphans,” and the orphanRemoval
>   attribute can be used to specify that orphaned entities should be
>   removed. For example, if an order has many line items and one of them
>   is removed from the order, the removed line item is considered an
>   orphan. If orphanRemoval is set to true, the line item entity will be
>   deleted when the line item is removed from the order.
>
> The orphanRemoval attribute in @OneToMany and @oneToOne takes a
>   Boolean value and is by default false.
>
> The following example will cascade the remove operation to the
>   orphaned customer entity when it is removed from the relationship:
>
> @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer", orphanRemoval="true") public
>   List getOrders() { ... }

```
@Entity
public class Owner {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    @NotNull(message="{NotNull}")
    @Size(min=2,max=15,message="{Size}")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull(message="{NotNull}")
    @Size(min=2,max=15,message="{Size}")
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Valid
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval="true")
    private Phone phone;

    @Valid
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval="true")
    private Pet pet;
```

And if you do this:

```
owner.set(new Phone(2222));
entityManager.merge(owner));
// update the owner phone
owner.set(new Phone(77777));
//the phone(2222) will be deleted
entityManager.merge(owner));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're using phone number as `@Id` for your `Phone` entity. And you cannot *change* the ID of an entity: you can either create a new one with a different ID, or `findById(number)` the existing one and update the value of the other fields (but not the `@Id` field, since that would again create a new entity).

If the phone number ("1234" or "2222") is all you need, then there's no point in having a `Phone` class to begin with. You can just use a `String` for that (if you want to be able to use +XX XXX ... format, or validate phone number length) or even an `Integer`.

If you *do* need the `Phone` class because it has other fields (like `Phone.totalCallsMade` or the like), then your program works as expected: different number, different entity.